# Allow moderators to handle any NAA/VLQ flags outside the queue

Tags: feature-request, flags, not-an-answer, moderator-tools

I just revisited an answer that was edited and noticed an empty flag overlay where information about pending flags is normally displayed. This was, of course, a new "not an answer" or "very low quality" flag that was [currently being hidden from me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243145/hide-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-in-the-moderator-flag-queue). Except the answer was both an attempt to answer the question *and* of acceptable quality, so my first instinct was to decline the flag, whichever it was. Which, of course, I couldn't, even though I was staring right at the very answer that was flagged.

I could, however, dispute the flag by visiting the post's moderator-only timeline and completing the Low Quality Posts review associated with it. It was a "not an answer" flag that was being incorrectly used to indicate a wrong answer, and the answer was terse enough — even more so after the author edit that appeared *within 10 seconds of the flag* — that I didn't trust reviewers not to vet it as "very low quality" subject to deletion.

Given that

1. the goal of hiding NAA/VLQ flags is simply to declutter the queue; and
2. the flag overlay has never been changed to not display hidden NAA/VLQ flags anyway, intentionally or not

... can I be allowed to handle the flag (and invalidate the review) when I'm looking directly at the post that was flagged?

This would have the added benefit of allowing me to communicate directly with the flagger (without leaving a public comment, pinging them in chat, or sending a mod message), something you can't do with review since most flaggers never know about the review tasks brought about by their flags and flag disputes don't usually come with a message.

Comment: So long as this doesn't encourage moderators to start handling flags about themselves on the spot, I don't see why this wouldn't be a good idea. That said, implementation of new features has been very strained of late it seems.

Comment: @TravisJ not sure I'm following the flow of thought between the question and your comment...

Comment: @TravisJ The mods pretty much know to never handle a flag that could be a potential conflict of interest - whether it's a flag about them or about an answer/comment by them. They know to leave it for another mod to handle.

Comment: @JonClements - For example, if you were on this page, and I flagged your comment, you would be able to handle it inline right now, as opposed to it hitting the queue and being at least somewhat displaced.

Comment: @bluefeet - Fair enough. It was only a mild concern.

Comment: @Travis J: It certainly wouldn't encourage us any more than it already does, given that we've had the flag overlay feature for many, many years.

Comment: Yeah, hiding this from moderators is more of an inconvenience than anything else. There are multiple workarounds. I won't disclose what they are in public, but this has happened to me and I've found a couple of different solutions. Travis's concerns are rather non-unique. If one of my answers were to, say, be flagged as "rude/abusive", that flag would instantly pop up. Moderators are elected because they're assumed to have the judgment and self-discipline required to abstain where there is a conflict of interest.

Comment: @BoltClock Your post inspired me to ask https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299872/245360.

Comment: @TravisJ For what it's worth, that example is moot because we see comment flags immediately anyway. Conflict of interest is a non-issue in practice; the site is big and conflicts are small.